IR Remote on an Arduino Single Button Press with Held to Increase or Decrease a Value
I'm having a bit of a struggle wrapping my head around what should be a fairly simple bit of code. For reference I'm using an Arduino and a cheap IR Receiver and Remote. I'm using a library and can confirm that the Arduino sees everything, can see all the commands and the like. If it matters the particular protocol is NEC. I can also confirm that when the button is held the library does properly set the flag that there is a repeat occurring. I can make a single button press work. But what I cannot get it do is if the button is held I want it to continually increase or decrease a value. The best I can get it to do is just loop forever until a new button is pressed.
I'm just learning programming so please excuse the spaghetti code. I'll leave out the setup and only focus on the loop portion here because that is where I'm having issues. Couple of quick notes, the command doesn't get overwritten for about 30 seconds...sometimes... I still haven't figured it out, its like a I'm still here type thing from the receiver. The library just spits out nothing, which makes sense as it is just a single pulse. Next, the IRDATA_FLAGS_IS_REPEAT I believe is a bool and when set just says true, but doesn't reset until another button press is detected. If just looking at IrReceiver.decodedIRData.flags and a button is held it will alternate between 0x1 and 0x0.
This works for a single button press.
void loop() {
if (IrReceiver.decode()) { //Setup for the library
Serial.println(IrReceiver.decodedIRData.command, HEX); //Debugging Purposes
Serial.println(IrReceiver.decodedIRData.flags, HEX); //Debugging Purposes
IrReceiver.resume(); //Enables receiving next command 
}
if (IrReceiver.decodedIRData.command == 0x18) { //0x18 is the correct command to increase
dataInc (); //Function to increase value
IrReceiver.decodedIRData.command = 0x0; //Resets the command
}
if (IrReceiver.decodedIRData.command == 0x52) {
dataDec (); //Function to decreae value
IrReceiver.decodedIRData.command == 0x0; //Resets the command
}

This actually works without an issue. The command can also be stored as a variable, but at some point it needs to be reset to something that doesn't do anything and 0x0 is not a command on the remote. So, that seems like a good value to me.
Now, where I'm having issues is getting the condition if the button is held down sorted. I've tried ChatGPT. It is actually been quite helpful, but I'm a hardware guy and not a software guy. The most functional bit of code I've gotten with regard to this looks a bit like this:
void loop() {
if (IrReceiver.decode()) { //Setup for the library
Serial.println(IrReceiver.decodedIRData.command, HEX); //Debugging Purposes
Serial.println(IrReceiver.decodedIRData.flags, HEX); //Debugging Purposes
IrReceiver.resume(); //Enables receiving next command 
}
if (IrReceiver.decodedIRData.command == 0x18) {
receivedCommand = IrReceiver.decodedIRData.command; //Variable to hold command
}
if (millis() - lastCommandTime > commandTimeout && currentCommand != 0x0) {
receivedCommand = 0x0; //Time out condition to reset
if (receivedCommand != currentCommand && receivedCommand != 0x0) {
currentCommand = receivedCommand; //Moves the command to a new variable
lastCommandTime = millis();
increaseHeld = false;
decreaseHeld = false;

if (currentCommand == 0x18) {
increaseHeld = true;
}
if (currentCommand == 0x52) {
decreaseHeld = true;
}
}

if (IrReceiver.decodedIRData.flags & IRDATA_FLAGS_IS_REPEAT) {
if (increaseHeld && millis - lastAdjustTime > adjustChangeDelay {
dataInc (); 
lastAdjustTime = millis(); //Update the last adjustment time
}
if (decreaseHeld && millis () - lastAdjustTime > adjustChangeDelay {
dataDec(); 
lastAdjustTime = millis(); //Update the last adjustment time
}
}

From my experimenting this just loops on itself and never stops. I'm sure it is something that I'm doing wrong, but I just cannot for the life of me figure it out. This also doesn't account for a single button press which I also need to be a thing. I assume I can just drop the increase or decrease part under the held detecting portions as appropriate, but maybe I'm wrong. I've been trying to focus on getting it to stop after holding the buttons right now. I'm pretty sure part of the problem is I need to reset the repeat flag, but when to do that? I have no clue. I've put it in the held portions before but it breaks and won't reset properly until another button press is registered. If I leave it, then sometimes after about 30 seconds or so it'll reset. But that is far from ideal too.

Do you want to call dataInc ()/dataDec() on repeated code from RC (hardware autorepeat) or with fixed rate while RC continues to send a code (software autorepeat)?
